# How to make POST request with a file as an attribute?

Tags: post

I'm trying to make a post request to the below URL to get a response

`http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convert` with the following param:

`upload` - the file being uploaded

My file is example.zip

```
curl --request POST 'http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convert' --data "upload=example.zip"
```

I tried the above command, but the response is not correct.

How to POST a file name to the `upload` param in the above url?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following format,

```
curl -X POST -F "upload=@/Users/testuser/Downloads/US20070254007_20071030.pdf" http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convert
```

NOTE: Please make sure your are using curl 7.54.0 at least.